# How to check for a float field and give a constraint for any action in Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

Suppose, in a custom module, I have fields for:

product_id, stock_location, stock_move, etc

And on another custom module I have a Float field, which will have a quantity, it will represent a fiscal year.

So, before I do any movement, I should check for this Float field, and somehow compare it's data with the product, or products I will be moving (product have a field called `'sale_price'` but it could be even a custom Float also on product)

I don't know if I'm explaining myself, but what I want is to compare these fields, and give a constraint to the action, if `custom_fiscal` Float field has a lower value than the `product_price` Float one, then show a `ValidationError` or something like that.

These fields are on two different modules, although that could be possible by inheritance and module dependence.

I'm not sure if this scenario could be achievable by using a `_constraint` or `_sql_constraint`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of different good options here:

1. Add the `_constraints` field to one module and force the module to depend on the other custom module.

   ```
   {'name': 'custom_a', 'depends': ['custom_b']}
   ```
2. Create an independent third custom module that links them together. You'll see Odoo core do this quite a bit with modules such as `stock_account`.

   ```
   {'name': 'custom_link', 'depends': ['custom_a', 'custom_b']}

   class Constrains(models.Model):
       _constraints = [(_check, 'My message...', ['my_field'])]
   ```